# How to add new DataRow into DataTable?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datarow

I have a `DataGridView` binded to a `DataTable` (`DataTable` binded to database). I need to add a `DataRow` to the `DataTable`. I'm trying to use the following code:

```
dataGridViewPersons.BindingContext[table].EndCurrentEdit();
DataRow row = table.NewRow();

for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
{
    row[i] = i.ToString();
}
```

But it doesn't work, `DataGridView` has never been added a new row. Please, tell me, how can I fix my code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datarow

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can try with this code - based on `Rows.Add method`

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.add?view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataRowCollection_Add_System_Data_DataRow_

Answer (score 33):

I found [dotnetperls examples on `DataRow`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datarow) very helpful. Code snippet for new `DataTable` from there:

```
static DataTable GetTable()
{
    // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Weight", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Breed", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    // Here we add five DataRows.
    table.Rows.Add(57, "Koko", "Shar Pei", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(130, "Fido", "Bullmastiff", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(92, "Alex", "Anatolian Shepherd Dog", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Charles", "Cavalier King Charles Spaniel", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(7, "Candy", "Yorkshire Terrier", DateTime.Now);

    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

//َCreating a new row with the structure of the table:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
table.Rows.Add(row);
```

//Giving values to the columns of the row(this row is supposed to have 28 columns):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
{
    row[i] = i.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to [add the row](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explicitly to the table

```
table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Answer (score 2):

If need to copy from another table then need to copy structure first:

```
DataTable copyDt = existentDt.Clone();
copyDt.ImportRow(existentDt.Rows[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Rows.Add();
```

Answer (score 0):

try `table.Rows.add(row);` after your `for` statement.

Answer (score -2):

```
    GRV.DataSource = Class1.DataTable;
            GRV.DataBind();

Class1.GRV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Delete();
        GRV.DataSource = Class1.DataTable;
        GRV.DataBind();
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This code is incomplete, and has nothing obvious to do with data rows.